# Split line having quotes in shell

Tags: unix, awk, sh

I have a line as mentioned below

```
"id":BinData(3,"dUpxQ3s018I0ijzNKWF+mQ=="),"id":BinData(3,"dUpxQ3s018I0ijzNKWF+lw=="),
```

I want the output in the following format so that i can store it in the array.

```
"id":BinData(3,"dUpxQ3s018I0ijzNKWF+mQ==")
"id":BinData(3,"dUpxQ3s018I0ijzNKWF+lw==")
```

How can i do this in `awk` or shell?

Answer (score 0):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you on same.

```
awk '{gsub(/,"id"/,"\n\"id\"")} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13, you missed the very last comma.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/,"id"/\n"id"/g;s/,$//' file
```

There are 2 commands. The first one replaces the `,` by a newline. The second one removes the extra `,` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a different way of thinking about it, here's an answer with GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='.{43}' 'RT{print gensub(/,$/,"",1,RT)}' file
"id":BinData(3,"dUpxQ3s018I0ijzNKWF+mQ==")
"id":BinData(3,"dUpxQ3s018I0ijzNKWF+lw==")
```